# Как вставить один код в другой?

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо вставить 1-й код во второй

**Есть первый код:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("bd.php");
$result88 = mysql_query("SELECT login,avatar,name,number FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4", $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result88))
    echo "<img src=$row[avatar]>" . $row['login'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['number'] . "<br />";
?>
```

**Есть второй код**

```
<?php
if    (!isset($myrow['login']) or $myrow['login']=='') 
{

print <<<HERE

<table  height="2000px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1000px" border="1"  cellspacing="1" style=" margin-bottom:35px; position: absolute; top:144px; left:450px;" >

<tr>

<td background="Stopka.jpg" valign="top" width="225px">
<UL style="position:relative; top:100px; left:30px;">
</td>

<td>
 <h3 style=" padding-left:35px; padding-top:20px;">Главная страница</h3>
 <hr style=" position:absolute; left:260px; top:40px" width=700px>
//ВОТ СЮДА НЕОБХОДИМО ПОДКЛЮЧИТЬ ИЛИ ВСТАВИТЬ 1 КОД**

</tr>
</table>
<img src="inyourcity.png" style="position:absolute; top:160px; left:467px" />

HERE;
?>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я вставляю скрипт, он не исполняется, а отображается на странице в виде кода, как будто я пишу что-то. Есть ли способы решения этой проблемы не в ущерб визуальному отображению сайта. И как можно настроить позицию выводимой информации из бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот таким способом

```
ob_start();
include 'links.php';
$include = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$content = <<<EOF
{$include}
EOF;
```

Comment: Помогло! Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

не используй хередок)
напиши обычный html с вставками php типа такого <?= ?>. скорее всего у тебя из-за этого ошибка.

Comment: у меня php в html и все это в php. У меня страница для гостей и пользователей отображается по разному.

Comment: позицию? в смысле сортировку из БД или как?

Comment: @kira то есть настроить css

Comment: @LaKO, Читаем про [синтаксис heredoc](http://www.php.ru/manual/language.types.string.html#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Мне там ничего не понятно) Популярным языком бы и с примерами.